# GUIStatics cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to get the user location name from the following code. I'm receiving error as GUIStatics cannot be resolved to a variable. How to correect it. Also can anyone tell is this code the correct method to achieve the location name or not.

```
package com.example.location;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.CellLocation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
LocationManager lmanager;
String provider;
String er="Please try again";
TextView t;
public static Context mContext; 
private double latitude,longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    lmanager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    lmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    locationUpdate();


}

private void locationUpdate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();
}

private void getAddress(double lat, double lon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Geocoder coder=new Geocoder(MainActivity.mContext,Locale.getDefault());
    try
    {
        List<Address> listaddress=coder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        Address obj=listaddress.get(0);
        String add=obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress=obj.getSubAdminArea()+","+obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.longitude=obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.latitude=obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity=obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState=obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();
        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    GUIStatics.latitude=latitude;
    GUIStatics.longitude=longitude;
    Log.v("Test", "IGA" + "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude);
    getAddress(latitude, longitude);
    if(location!=null)
    {
        lmanager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    else if(status== LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE)
    { 
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 


}

 }
```

My manifest file is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.location"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.location.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me

Comment: Have you got the solution/